# SQL Server Transactional Replication with local Publisher/Distributor and Azure Subscription

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, replication

Is is possible to have a Transactional Replication configured with local Publisher/Distributor and with Azure Subscription?
I was thinking to create an Historical DB on Azure VM that replicates the production DB, copying only insert and update operations.

I have worked only on local DBs, never tried to work with DB in cloud, so i was curious.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to configure Transactional Replication with a local Publisher and an Azure Subscriber. You can replicate data from your on-premises (local) database to an Azure SQL Database

find the below link for a detailed guide

[Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver16)